# C++ - Return multidimensional array from function

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I am writing a code for Cellular Automata and I need an evolution function to calculate the state of the automata after a time step.
I choose to call this function evol, to test it I created an elementary function in C++. Unfortunately it does not compile since the compiler cannot understand that I need it to return an array. Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int N = 51; // Size of the grid; two columns/rows are added at the beginning and the end of the array (no evolution of the CA on the boundaries)

class Cell{
    //defining whats a cell here        
};

void showCA(Cell CA[N+2][N+2]){
    //function to print the CA grid in the terminal         
}


Cell[N+2][N+2] evol(Cell CA[N+2][N+2]){
    return CA;
}

int main()
{
     // Initialisation
    cout << "Initialisation" << endl;
    static Cell CA[N+2][N+2];
    // some code here to initialize properly the Cell array.
    showCA(CA);
    CA = evol(CA);
    showCA(CA);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler returns this error :

```
error: expected unqualified-id
Cell[N+2][N+2] evol(Cell CA[N+2][N+2]){
```

Any idea on how I should implement this ?

Comment: use a semi colon to fix that error. You probably want to use vectors as well.

Comment: What does `N` actually represent? You have a number of curious statements in your code. What do you want to achieve finally?

Comment: Create a class to represent a multi-dimensional array (probably as a wrapper to provide 2D addressing into a `std::vector`). Return an instance of that class.

Comment: The standard way for the past decades has been to provide a target array as an argument to evol, which would return nothing or perhaps bool, indicating success. Probably the caller would have two arrays which would swap roles as source and target after each evolution.

Comment: Your syntax for declaring a function returning an array is incorrect. Use `Cell evol(Cell CA[N+2][N+2])[N+2][N+2]` rather than `Cell[N+2][N+2] evol(Cell CA[N+2][N+2])` to get a more helpful error message.

Comment: I corrected the missing semicolon after the return statement of      evol. I'll try to use std::vector or std::array during the day and update.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Edited : N represents the size of the array. The final goal of this code will be to make operations on CA, via the evol() function. Here I pasted an elementary version of evol that does nothing but return the original CA. It should at the end return another Cell array of the same size with different Cell s in it.

Comment: Working with std::array or std::vector worked. I slightly modified the code such as evol is now a void function modifying CA. It can be written like this : void evol(Cell (&CA)[N+2][N+2]){// rules of CA modification here}. CA = evol(CA); is then now just evol(CA);. Thanks for the help and suggestions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot return arrays from functions:**

> **§ 8.3.5/8**
>
> Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things.

If you are wishing to return raw, C-style arrays from functions, then you have to use a reference or pointer. For example, here's how it is done using a reference (you can do the same using a pointer by replacing `&` with `*`):

```c++
Cell (&evol(Cell (&CA)[N+2][N+2]))[N+2][N+2];
```

However, this is very unintuitive and hard to read. If your compiler supports the latest standard (C++11) the return type can be cleaned up using a trailing return type:

```c++
auto evol(Cell (&CA)[N+2][N+2]) -> Cell(&)[N+2][N+2];
```

But again, this is probably still harder to read.

---

C++11 facilitates the handling of C-style arrays with the container `std::array<>`. Non-C++11 code should use `std::vector<>`:

```c++
using Cells = std::array<std::array<Cell, N+2>, N+2>;

Cells const& evol(Cells const& CA);
```

Comment: If the array size is large returning a std::array may be inefficient or dangerous (because of, you guess it, stack overflow).

Comment: @PeterSchneider I doubt `std::array` will have any more overhead that a regular array. And in any case the size for a potential stack overflow is exactly the same when using an array vs `std::array`, and one should use a `std::vector` in that case.

Comment: True with respect to overflow; but returning a std::array just copies lots of bytes around, doesn't it (as opposed to returning a pointer or a std::vector with move semantics).

Comment: Additionally, if you return a reference to a C array you better don't have it on the stack.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Why should it not be on the stack?

Comment: Because it ceases to exist upon return?

Comment: I assumed we were talking about the statically allocated array in the OPs code. If one was to return a *reference* to an array allocated on the heap, you would get a memory leak as one would have to dereference the local pointer to the array to obtain the reference. Better to return a pointer to the allocated heap data instead.

Comment: If we are just copying pointers and always work on the original array, the whole question is moot and there is no need for references to begin with. But if we pass e.g. std::array or custom classes by value into the function and return a reference to that, or to a local copy, we are screwed.

Comment: @PeterSchneider But it isn't clear from OP's code whether a copy is needed (it seems to suggest that). If you need copies, then you need to make a copy at some point. Passing a target output parameter doesn't help and makes the code more confusing. Returning by value is fine.

Comment: @juanchopanza As I said, if no copy is needed and all operations happen on the original array then nothing needs to be returned, so the OP's question would be unnecessary. Therefore the question implies copying the array out of the function. (It looks to me like an idiom one would use in garbage collected languages with cheap allocators, e.g. C#.) Returning by value is inefficient if we use std::array.

Comment: @PeterSchneider There is no problem with returning the array by value. The copy will be elided. *If* it is not elided for whatever reason (exotic C++ implementation/platform, pre-standards compiler etc.) *then* one can start thinking of clever ways to fix that problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza interesting, I wasn't aware that RVO is so commonplace now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> CellArray;
CellArray Cells(N+2);  // resize main dimension
for (size_t i=0; i<N+2; i++)
    Cells[i].resize(N+2); // resize all cells of main dimension
```

to hold your cell array, but you also need to add a copy constructor and operator= in Cell class

```
class Cell {
public:
    Cell() { ... default ctor code here ... }
    Cell(const Cell &c) { *this = c; }

    Cell &operator=(const Cell&c)
    {
        if (this != &c)
        {
            ... copy data from c members to this members here ...
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Your evol function then can return a CellArray:

```
CellArray evol(CellArray &c)
{
   CellArray r;
   ... do some calculations with c and r ...
   return r;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need a move ctor? And perhaps, to avoid funny surprises for your successor, a move assignment? This all sounds almost ridiculously overkill.

Comment: @PeterSchneider There's nothing to be moved here (RVO). But if it makes sense for a class to be move copyable and move assignable, it should allow these operations.

Answer (score 0):

once you have declared a variable using the array syntax like you have:

```
Cell CA[N+2][N+2];
```

you cannot assign `CA` to be something else. You can only assign values to its contents. Hence,

```
CA = evol(CA);
```

is wrong.

You can do the following:

```
Cell (*CA2)[N+2] = evol(CA);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the number of elements seems to be fixed, I suggest you use the `std::array` container:

```
const int N = 51;
typedef std::array<std::array<Cell,N+2>, N+2> datatype;
```

You can then use this type as a return type:

```
datatype Evol( const datatype& d );
```

You can access elements just as if it was a "C" array:

```
datatype d;
Cell c;
d[10][20] = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest encapsulate your array into a class. You cannot return an array, but you can return an object that contains an array.